# Which game type in COD: MW3 gets you the most XP?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Obviously this changes based on your proficiency in a game type along with a myriad of other variables, but generally speaking, which game type in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 gains you the most XP (on average)?

Comment: In general, objective game modes (domination, kill confirmed, etc) give more xp than 'slayer modes' (tdm, ffa). S&D gives very little from a xp/min standpoint due to its more 'tactical', slower-paced nature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been having really good luck with Kill Confirmed.  You get XP for kills, plus for their tags, plus if you can find a) other tags from friendly kills or b) red tags from enemy kills you'll also get XP.  A really good thing to try and do is to go back and get your own tags after your killed, it's a +250 XP bump.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing hardcore games the last few times, and in general I get a lot more kills (and die a lot more, too).

I would, too, say Hardcore Kill Confirmed, but it might not be easy to find a lobby for that. If not, then play Hardcore Domination and stay at defense, if playing run&gun is not your thing.

Answer (score 3):

Team Defender gives you double XP when your team has the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Team defender is good.

If you get about maybe 5 to 6 kills a game you should level up fast. At this rate you get about 500+ XP each game.

Answer (score 1):

Search & Destroy if you're good. Just go around getting about 10 kills or more a game and you'll level like no other, but don't do it if you're not down to try hard all day.

Answer (score 1):

Free for all.  If you're a good player, FFA is the best mode to gain XP.  I've already gotten to tenth prestige and restarted, and now I'm in my 4th prestige, so technically that  makes it my 14th.  So far, I have only played around 4 days, 23 hours total.

Answer (score 1):

Headquarters Pro. Play as a Specialist, and you get bonuses for getting killstreaks. Sometimes up to 30000 with bonuses, so HQ for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the Specialist strike package and play team defender.  If you are good enough you can get the specialist bonus.  If your team has the flag, it's basically raining xp.

Answer (score -1):

I am finding the new community playlists not only fun, but drop zone can give ridiculous amounts of XP if you play right.